# Method for using volume up button to take pictures iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a method to call to be able to enable/disable the feature of taking pictures with the volume up button?

Comment: It seems as though this is possible however i'm not sure how - camera+ does it that's why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed that using `imagePicker.showsCameraControls=NO;` and by setting a custom overlay of the `cameraOverlayView` of the `UIImagePickerController`, the volume button is disabled. Now the problem is that you have to redefine the behaviors of the camera(zoom, ect).

Answer (score 2):

Short of jailbreaking your device or using private api, this cannot be done, much less approved by Apple, using the standard methods.

If your device is jailbroken, I believe there is an [Activator](https://github.com/rpetrich/libactivator) setting that will allow you to accomplish this.

Also, there is a package in Cydia that does exactly this called [**SnapTap**](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.openhebrew.snaptap).

Comment: Why downvote this answer? Maybe it's not the solution, but it's pretty correct.